# UserScript to navigate to the next comic page on 8 Bit Theater by clicking on the panel on the current page

Tags: javascript, userscript

I wrote this UserScript for personal use to allow me to click the main comic panel in order to navigate to the next panel, a feature which I consider essential for any webcomic, to the point that before this script I simply did not bother trying to read any comics that don't have this feature.

This is for use on the comic series that starts with https://www.nuklearpower.com/2001/03/02/episode-001-were-going-where/. It's designed to only work with this comic series, and I was hoping to upload it to GreasyFork or some other way I could share it with other interested people. Before that, though, I wanted to get some feedback on the script, see if there are any glaring mistakes or flaws that can be improved upon.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Click 8 Bit Theater to go to next Panel
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.nuklearpower.com/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=nuklearpower.com
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* globals comicDiv */

(function() {
    'use strict';
    // If there is a comic panel on the page
    var comicDiv = document.getElementById("comic");
    if(comicDiv){
        // Create a wrapper anchor element
        var wrapper = document.createElement("a");
        var nextLink = document.querySelector("a[rel=next]");
        if(nextLink){
            // Set the wrapper's href to that of the next link, if found
            wrapper.href = nextLink.href;
            wrapper.title = "next";
            // Insert the wrapper between the comicDiv and the comic itself
            wrapper.appendChild(comicDiv.firstElementChild);
            comicDiv.appendChild(wrapper);

        }
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if(comicDiv){
```

What happens if you don't find the div? For example, if the site owners change their HTML so that's not the ID anymore?

I suggest at minimum a `console.log()` statement. However, you could also display an HTML banner on the page, or come up with some other way of communicating that the script isn't working as intended.

---

Before sharing this, it would be helpful to have a specific and concise description (and your name). Currently, your description and author fields still have the default values.

```
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
```